# How should a function written through the Module be written in the FindMinimum correctly?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerics, mathematical-optimization, eigenvalues

There is a function that is written using a module `dE[m1_?NumericQ, m2_?NumericQ, e0_?NumericQ] := Module[{}, ee1 = en[1, m1, m2, e0][[1]]; ee2 = en[1, m1, m2, e0][[2]]; ee = ee1 + ee2; Return[ee]]`. I would like to find its minimum using `FindMinimum`.

How should the function `dE[m1_?NumericQ, m2_?NumericQ, e0_?NumericQ]` be written in `FindMinimum`?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
mi[m1_, m2_] := m1*m2/(m1 + m2);

VC[r_, e0_] := -(1/(e0*r));

rmax = 10;
zmax = 10;

Hp[m1_, m2_, e0_, 
   B_] := -1/2/mi[m1, m2]*
    Laplacian[\[Psi][r, z], {r, \[Theta], z}, "Cylindrical"] + 
   VC[r, e0]*\[Psi][r, z] + r^2*B^2;

en[m1_?NumericQ, m2_?NumericQ, e0_?NumericQ, B_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{}, {vals, funs} = 
    NDEigensystem[{Hp[m1, m2, e0, B] + \[Psi][r, z]}, \[Psi][r, 
      z], {r, 0, rmax}, {z, -zmax, zmax}, 10, 
     Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \
{"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.05}}}, 
       "Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", "MaxIterations" -> 10000}}];
   Return[vals[[1 ;; 2]] - 1]];

FindMinimum[{dE[m1_?NumericQ, m2_?NumericQ, e0_?NumericQ] = Module[{},
    ee1 = en[1, m1, m2, e0][[1]];
    ee2 = en[1, m1, m2, e0][[2]];
    ee = ee1 + ee2;
    Return[ee]], (0.1 < m1 < 10) && (0.1 < m2 < 10) && (1 < e0 < 
     10)}, {{m1, 0.3}, {m2, 0.3}, {e0, 14}}, AccuracyGoal -> 3, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 3, 
 EvaluationMonitor :> {Print["m1=", m1, "   m2=", m2, "   e0=", e0, 
    "   dE=", ee]}]

(*In[82]:= dE[0.3, 0.3, 14]*)

(*Out[82]= -1.37597*)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but there are some basic syntax mistakes. This should work, though I don't know how long it will take to actually find the minimum.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
mi[m1_, m2_] := m1*m2/(m1 + m2);

VC[r_, e0_] := -(1/(e0*r));

rmax = 10;
zmax = 10;

Hp[m1_, m2_, e0_, 
   B_] := -1/2/mi[m1, m2]*
    Laplacian[\[Psi][r, z], {r, \[Theta], z}, "Cylindrical"] + 
   VC[r, e0]*\[Psi][r, z] + r^2*B^2;

en[m1_?NumericQ, m2_?NumericQ, e0_?NumericQ, B_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{vals, funs}, {vals, funs} = 
    NDEigensystem[{Hp[m1, m2, e0, B] + \[Psi][r, z]}, \[Psi][r, 
      z], {r, 0, rmax}, {z, -zmax, zmax}, 10, 
     Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \
{"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.05}}}, 
       "Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", "MaxIterations" -> 10000}}];
   vals[[1 ;; 2]] - 1
   ];
dE[m1_?NumericQ, m2_?NumericQ, e0_?NumericQ] := Module[{ee1, ee2},
  {ee1, ee2} = en[1, m1, m2, e0];
  ee = ee1 + ee2
  ]

FindMinimum[
 dE[m1, m2, e0],
 {{m1, 0.3}, {m2, 0.3}, {e0, 14}},
 AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3,
 EvaluationMonitor :> {Print["m1=", m1, "   m2=", m2, "   e0=", e0, 
    "   dE=", ee]}
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you explain please why `Module` doesn't work inside `FindMinimum`? Is there any way to put `Module` inside `FindMinimum`? Because I would like to print `ee1` and `ee2` using `EvaluationMonitor`.

Comment: @MamMam your code didn't work because you put a function declaration (`dE[m1_?NumericQ, m2_?NumericQ, e0_?NumericQ] = ...`) inside `FindMinimum`. If you want to `ee1` and `ee2`, just use a Print inside the Module or don't scope them at all.